# Perl DBIx::Class DateTime subtraction

Tags: perl, dbix-class

What's wrong with this code? I am using perl's `DateTime` module with `DBIx::Class`.

```
my $entry_rs = $schema->resultset('table_name')->search_rs(             
    {                                                                       
        table_id      => $row->table_id,                                    
        utc_timestamp => { '<', \'DateTime->now()->subtract(days => 180)' },
    },                                                                      
)->all;
```

I am using PostgreSQL, `utc_timestamp` type is timestamp. If I calculate, `DateTime->now()->subtract(days => 180)` and store in variable and substitute the value, then it works.

Error:

> DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI::_dbh_execute(): DBI Exception: DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  column "datetime" does not exist ??

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing Perl code as literal SQL to the database. This can't work. Try something like this:

```
my $dt       = DateTime->now()->subtract(days => 180);
my $parser   = $schema->storage->datetime_parser;
my $entry_rs = $schema->resultset('table_name')->search_rs(             
    {                                                                       
        table_id      => $row->table_id,                                    
        utc_timestamp => { '<', $parser->format_datetime($dt) },
    },                                                                      
)->all;
```

This code uses [`datetime_parser` in `DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aStorage%3a%3aDBI#datetime_parser) to retrieve the `DateTime::Format` class appropriate for your database. Then it calls `format_datetime` on that class to convert the `DateTime` object to a string that can be passed to the DB.

Comment: @nwellnhoff - that's exactly what I did. Thanks though. I was thinking, there is a way to trick perl code in there..Thanks though..